# Perform a action on specific time using Parse

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I want to declare a winner of a game when ever its time expires.
is there any functionality in parse to perform an action on a specific time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qaiser,

As far as I am aware, there is no way to use a timer in the CloudCode on Parse. They have a 3 second timeout on cloud operations. I am assuming from your question statement that the time expires on a client device and then you want to use Parse to send a message to all other participants of the game that the time has expired and a winner has been named.

Personally, I would use a single timer in the "Leader" of the game to update "gameOver" and "winner"  keys within a "game" object that holds all relevant data for your game. However, this structure is subject to the moving pieces within your specific game (without more information, I cannot suggest an alternative). In each client, I would use a timer to request an update of the "game" object every couple of seconds to keep non-leader users up to date. Once those fields have been set, then their clients know that the game has ended and a winner has been named.

I am unaware of any functionality in Parse to implement a model-observer scheme where Parse would automatically send an update to every observing client. If this is key to your game, then perhaps looking at Firebase would be helpful because that is integral to the way that Firebase structures its database scheme. However, the system is slightly more rudimentary and hierarchal than Parse, so it might not suit the rest of your application quite as well.

Hope this helps!